# Change DataFrame Dates From UK to US in Python

Tags: python, date

I have a set of dates that I would like to change in a dataframe. I think some are incorrectly being read as British dates and I don't know how to change them over.

For instance, 01/04/2018 (April 1st) is being read as a the fourth of January. I've tried to even hackjob this in Excel by using TextToConvert, but it still reads the date as the 4th of January when I mean the 1st of April. Other dates such as the 22/04/18 are read just fine as the 22nd of April. Everything with a day value under 12 though is sadly flipped.

Please advise on a clean way to change this in Python. None of the parseDT methods I've tried have worked. The data is currently a datetime type.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use pandas, the cleanest way to deal with this is with the `dayfirst` parameter of `pd.to_datetime`, which defaults to `False`:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime('01/04/2018')
Timestamp('2018-01-04 00:00:00')

pd.to_datetime('01/04/2018', dayfirst=True)
Timestamp('2018-04-01 00:00:00')
```